# Is this awkward reuse of a verb between subjects correct?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, phrasal-verbs, infinitives, ellipses

From a [Library of Congress article about Freud](https://www.loc.gov/exhibits/freud/freud02.html):

> ...patients tended to perform for the camera and doctors to record the most photogenic.

This sentence seems to reuse the verb *tended* between the subjects *patients* and *doctors*.

I think this is an instance of [gapping](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-gapping-1690885). I have seen it in simpler cases like:

> Alice cooked the rice, and Bob the beans.

I can't imagine anyone speaking like this casually, but it feels OK in writing. However, the more complex Freud sentence feels wrong. Is it?

The object of the reused verb is an infinitive instead of a plain noun -- is that the problem?

Or maybe that "tended to ____" behaves like a single compound verb, and the *tended* part cannot be reused?

Comment: I also think it would be better to say "most photogenic patients", "most photogenic moments", etc. instead of the bare "photogenic". But that is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Seems fine. Parallel construction so there's no problem. People write differently to how they speak, except online maybe. But even online tbh.

Comment: I'd not use it; I'd want the parallelism to be tightened to say '...patients tended to perform for the camera and doctors to strive for the natural'. It smacks of zeugma as it is.

Comment: The point is that doctors are *not* striving for the natural but favoring the hams, the ones who know how to pose for the camera.

Comment: I don't understand the verb *record* here. Is it being used  intransitively like "My voice doesn't record well"?

Comment: **record** is being used transitively; in context it means to create a photographiic record (of the photogenic), which would involve multiple pictures over time to document, photographically, the patients' mental states as manifested in facial expression.  The doctors (tended) to record the most photogenic.

Comment: It makes perfect sense when the preceding information is included *Charcot documented the stages of hysteria with photography. **This practice was suspect**, however, **since patients tended to perform for the camera** and doctors to record the most photogenic.* But I would add a comma after "camera"

Comment: I went down a garden path and couldn't find my way out!

Answer (score 4):

The only problem with

> Patients tended to perform for the camera and doctors [tended] to record the
> most photogenic [patients].

is that it lacks a “comma of clarity” as shown in

> Alice cooked the rice, and Bob [cooked] the beans.

Without commas, we’re led down some pretty exciting garden paths:

> Patients tended to perform for the camera and doctors . . .
>
> Alice cooked the rice and Bob . . .

Comment: Yes, my first reading was that patients performed for the camera *and* doctors

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing incorrect about the sentence; to me it sounds at most mildly awkward. Indeed, in their discussion of gapping, Huddleston & Pullum (2002) give this example (p. 1338):

> Kim was hoping to go to university and Pat to join the family business.

Comment: I think the awkwardness is subjective.  I find this sort of construction very offputting. I don't really know what good purpose it serves.

Comment: 'Go to university' and 'join the family business' are alternative future courses. But 'perform for the camera' and 'record the most photogenic' are quite a bit further apart semantically. Without a comma, OP's example is also garden-pathy. There are reasons other than non-grammaticality to consider a sentence suboptimal (or even unacceptable).

Answer (score 0):

> Or maybe that "tended to ____" behaves like a single compound verb, and the tended part cannot be reused?

No, there's no grammatical rule of that nature here preventing reuse of **tend**.  This is a stylistic choice. IMO, a dubious one, because I don't  see it as serving any expository purpose. Moreover, I suspect readers who are delighted by it or impressed by it would be greatly outnumbered by the readers who get tripped up by it or dislike it.

**tend** can be complemented by  a clause headed by the marked infinitive or by multiple such clauses.  It's like  the verb "help".

> Tom helped to set up the chairs and Dick <sup>(helped)</sup> to position the lectern and Harry <sup>(helped)</sup> to adjust the lights.

Here's a double-whammy version:

> Manny tended to work on the Chevies, Moe to work on the Fords, and Jack on everything else.